# Object access via Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, mongoose

I want to acccess the fields category and specCategory. I applied `*ngFor="let x of data" {{x._id.category}}` but it is not working. Whats wrong with it?

I am using aggregate functionality to group the categories.

```
  $group: {
              _id: {
        category: "$category",
        specCategory: "$specCategory"
    },


                min: {$min: '$price'},
                max: {$max: 500},
               total:{$sum:1}
            }
```

**Result:**

```
[ { _id: { category: 'Wasser & Wind', specCategory: 'Surfen' }, min: 49, max: 500, total: 1 }, { _id: { category: 'Reisen', specCategory: 'Hotel' }, min: 49, max: 500, total: 1 } ]
```

I will need to access the category, specCategory and total value

Comment: That is because your object isn't an array. Angular2 doesn't support iterating over maps, only over arrays

Answer (score 1):

you miss closing curly brackets.

```
{ _id: { category: 'Reisen', specCategory: 'Hotel' },
```

should be

```
{ _id: { category: 'Reisen', specCategory: 'Hotel' }},
```

I added [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/odHNPWXjWajrev8dn1TQ?p=preview) take a look on file: app/app.component.ts

Comment: Ok, the complete data structure look like this [ { _id: { category: 'Wasser & Wind', specCategory: 'Surfen' },
    min: 49,
    max: 500,
    total: 1 },
  { _id: { category: 'Reisen', specCategory: 'Hotel' },
     min: 49,
     max: 500,
    total: 1 } ]